# Having ''unprotected'' issues while using Tor over VPN

Tags: settings

Having troubles with the location with the Tor browser;it shows my ''location''saying that i am not protected or secured in the main site of Nord VPN which is the VPN i use,while if i change my browser to Internet Explorer I am secured.
Would like to know if this is a leak or a conflict between Tor and the VPN or if this is normal ???

P.s : don't wanna leave the Tor browser,please help !!!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it showing your real location, the location of the VPN exit, or the location of the Tor exit node? It's not clear from your description. In what order are you linking Tor and the VPN together?

Comment: Hi Richard,that is not my ''real location'' of course not,i always click on the VPN first,then the Tor over VPN server;i did notice this few days ago,really don't know if this is wrong or it is normal,just worried cause I did buy the VPN few days ago but this conflict is taking my attention,if you guys can help me,would be appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely a conflict between your VPN and Tor. Here's my thoughts:

Nord VPN gives you a specific IP address to use. When you connect through IE, you have the VPN IP, so you are "protected."

Tor gives you a different IP address. When you connect through the Tor Browser, the VPN sees a different IP, so it thinks that you aren't connected to the VPN, and thus "unprotected."

To visualize the internet traffic, here's what happens through Internet Explorer:

```
Device (ISP, "unprotected") ==> Nord VPN ("protected")
```

And when you go through Tor,

```
Device (ISP, "unprotected") ==> Nord VPN ("protected") ==> Tor (random IP, "unprotected")
```

Since Nord doesn't own the Tor IP, it says you are unprotected. In reality, you are still protected by Tor and your VPN.